# Is it possible to know where variable were set?

Tags: php, variables

I was wondering if it is possible to see where variable were set in php code?
That would make debugging really easier as i assign different values to same variable based on some condition.

Comment: Interesting question. While I don't have the answer, I'll be following this thread. Using Zend Studio here, which is a pretty full-blown PHP IDE, yet it doesn't seem to offer such a functionality...

Comment: I'm working in PHPDesigner and i can't find anything like so also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

However, many good PHP IDEs (at least [NuSphere's](http://www.nusphere.com/) phpEd, I'm *sure* Zend must have that too?) offer a possibility to jump to the point at which the variable was first used, and highlight all its occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering about debugging. Do this.

```
if(condition)
{
    echo "1";
    $var = "something";
}
elseif(othercondition)
{
    echo "2";
    $var = "something";
}
...
```

Etc, this is really quickly done and you can see the number quickly in the output or a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) you can install the [SourceCookifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) plugin.

From the website: "A plugin which uses Exuberant Ctags to parse either only the currently activated source file or multiple files of so-called sessions. The results are shown and can be browsed in a treeview inside of a dockable window."

From my own experience: it just works - for variables, functions, properties, methods, classes, interfaces... and some HTML and javascript stuff too.